# Input in an array with no dimension without array list

Tags: java, arrays, input, size

I want to create a program that reads int values from the user until a value that is not an int is introduced. Then i want to get how many numbers are equal.
I tried this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equals {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = keyboard;
        int index = 0;
        int equals = 0;
        while(keyboard.hasNextInt()){
            keyboard.nextInt();
            index++;
        }
        int[] equals = new int[index];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < index ; i++){
            int aux = input.nextInt();
            values[i] = aux;
            for(int b = 0 ; b < index ; b++){
                if(aux == values[b]){
                    equals++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(equals);
    }
}
```

This code doesnt work because the keyboard scanner only gets the number of values introduced by the user and i use that for the array size but i cant get each individual value to compare. I cant use array lists.

Comment: Why not ask user how many numbers they plan to enter, initialize an `Array` of that size and then fill it with user input and check to see how many are duplicates

Comment: this a problem to do in school and they dont want us to ask the total

Comment: Well a hint: Unless you want the user to input everything twice, you cannot have a loop to count how many times the user inputs an int, and then another loop to assign the input to an array

Comment: Yes i got that wrong, that is asking to input values again, i was trying to find a way to get the values from the first input

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use array lists, what can you use?  Can you use this?

```
 int[] values = new int[0];

 while(keyboard.hasNextInt()){
        values  = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length + 1);
        values[values.length-1] = keyboard.nextInt();
        index++;
   }
```

And if you aren't allowed to do the arrays class, you can resize the array manually like this, and use this function instead of Arrays.copyOf:

```
private int[] resize(int[]s, int capacity) {
    int[] copy = new int[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        copy[i] = s[i];
        s = copy;
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: it says i cant use methods from the classes **Arrays**, **Integers**, and **Math** from the package **java.lang**

Comment: This will copy a new `Array` every time a user inputs an `int`. Wouldn't it be better to create a copy of the array that is bigger than just one slot bigger than the last? And then once input is done, trim it down to the size

Comment: @JASOS I edited with a solution that doesn't use Arrays

Comment: they also dont let me create another method besides the method main

Comment: im doing this program with arrays i dont know if i can do it without using an array but i dont think it would be possible

Comment: @JASOS you can simply insert the code from the function inside your main class instead of making it a function.  Since this is your homework, ill let you figure out how to do that.